# Ordering an array of objects by object value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

If I have an array with objects like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [img] => image1.jpg
            [order] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [img] => image2.jpg
            [order] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [img] => image3.jpg
            [order] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [img] => image4.jpg
            [order] => 4
        )
)
```

How can I then sort the array by the objects "order" value? In this case the order should be: image1.jpg, image3.jpg, image2.jpg, image4.jpg.

Comment: You're looking for [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.3+

```
usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->order == $b->order) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->order < $b->order) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

For < PHP 5.3 just change the anonymous function for a predefined named function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an exemple for your code :

```
function sortImage($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->img == $b->img) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->img < $b->img) ? -1 : 1;
}


usort($youArray, "sortImage");
```

edit: in your case you have order property but php can also compare "image1" and "image2" strings

Answer (score 0):

You should use this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

You have to write a comparison function, to be used as the second argument to `usort`.